# Download all photos from Facebook album

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am using this code...

It seems to be working somewhat, but the problem is I am getting the photo thumbnail not the original photo.

How can I get the original photo URL?

```
$albums = $fb->get('/me/albums', $token)->getGraphEdge()->asArray();

$photos = $fb->get("/{$album_id}/photos?fields=picture", $token)->getGraphEdge()->asArray();
foreach($photos as $photo){
$photo['picture'];
}
```

output

```
https://fbcdn-photos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/v/t1.0-0/p130x130/xxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxx_n.jpg?oh=xxxxxxxxxxxx6&oe=56CA24CB&__gda__=xxxx_xxxxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As referenced from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo), *fields=picture* returns link to the 100px wide representation of the photo.  Instead you should use

*fields=images*.

It returns `list<PlatformImageSource>`  and PlatformImageSource has [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/platform-image-source/) structure.

**source** element should return the URI of the image

Comment: thanks for answer, but fields=link returns  url of photo webpage, not photo url like this: facebook.com/foo.jpg.
edit: fields=images working perfect. thanks for reference.